# Use Powershell to change password on login

Tags: powershell

At the moment I'm building a login Script on powershell basis.
This login script should be able to change the users Password on login and change it back to the original on logout.

Problem here being that I want to change a Password of a domain user, the same user as the one who is logged in obviously

Now I found some neat stuff like the old, net.exe. but it all says I don't have the rights to change the password in the Domain.

I really can't believe that this is something impossible cause the user himself can change the password too.

Otherwise I'd have to find out how to run a login script with a domain admin...

Edit:

ok I'll try to explain our setup we have a so called VMware View environment, in which every user can login once. now we have the problem that there are accounts with generally known passwords, and some people find it highly amusing to steal others sessions. I've thought about it and making a little script that changes and then resets the password would be a neat little solution. I hope I was of help^^

It would be really helpfull if I could get some thoughts on this
Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there is better a way.

Comment: ok I'll try to explain our setup
we have a so called VMware View environment, in which every user can login once.
now we have the problem that there are accounts with generally known passwords, and some people find it highly amusing to steal others sessions. I've thought about it and making a little script that changes and then resets the password would be a neat little solution.
I hope I was of help^^

Comment: I would add you comment as an edit to your question...

Comment: How would your envisoned scenario help against stealing passwords if the script changes it back to the original on logout?

Comment: @Attila Password stealing is not the problem. Session Stealing is. if every account has the same password the users can steal sessions from others once they are already logged it. so my thought was to change password after login and before logout so that stealing becomes impossible

Comment: This is not a programming question.  I belongs on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](http://itnsomnia.wordpress.com/2008/04/08/change-a-domain-accounts-password-from-the-command-line/) might help you.

Also, according to the link above, you need to be on the domain controller to use `net` to change password (or supply the "/domain" option).

Comment: Trouble is I'm looking for a way to change the password of the user without needing domain admin rights. If I execute my script with a domain admin, no problem what so ever. if I execute with a normal user... nope won't work

Comment: You could try these too: [SriptingGuy](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/08/17/how-to-change-a-user-s-active-directory-password-with-powershell.aspx) and [OrcsWeb](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/james/fun-with-powershell-domain-authentication/), but according to this [MS article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754395.aspx), you need to be member of Account Operators, Domain Admins or Enterprise Admins.

Comment: thanks @Attila that should clear my problem, 
I'll have to think of something else then